# How can I find points of non differentiablity in the given function?

Tags: functions

How can I find points of ND in this function. Any help is appreciated...
$$F(x) = (x²+x).|e^{x-1}|.(|x-2|)^5$$

Comment: What have you tried? Surely you are familiar with the non-differentiability of absolute value functions?

Answer (score 0):

$F$ is differentiable everywhere. In fact:

1. $x \mapsto x^2+x$ is differentiable everywhere;
2. $x \mapsto |e^{x-1}| = e^{x-1}$ is differentiable everywhere;
3. $\varphi : x \mapsto |x-2|^5$ is differentiable everywhere, even in $x=2$, because:

$$ D_+\varphi(2) = \lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{|x-2|^5}{x-2} = \lim_{x\to 2^+} \frac{|x-2|^5}{|x-2|} = \lim_{x\to 2^+} |x-2|^4 = 0 $$
and
$$ D_-\varphi(2) = \lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{|x-2|^5}{x-2} = \lim_{x\to 2^-} \frac{|x-2|^5}{-|x-2|} = \lim_{x\to 2^-} -|x-2|^4 = 0. $$
Note that the product of functions differentiables is also differentiable, and that for functions of one variable, differentiability and derivability are equivalent.